# how to change history-level to activity in camunda using cli

Tags: camunda, jboss-cli

How can i override `<history-level>full</history-level>` to `<history-level>activity</history-level>` in camunda using cli(jboss cli)

Answer (score 1):

finally following works for me.

```
/subsystem=subsytem_name/process-engines=default:write-attribute(name=history-level,value=activity)
```